# How to create a new window/panel when pressing a button in Flutter at the location of the button

Tags: flutter

I wanted to create a small panel when the user clicked a button in flutter. I wanted the panel to be on top of the button and when the user clicks anywhere outside of the panel, it will close it.
Similar to this one [reference image left is the button and right is the panel above the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI2PN.png)

I wanted it to be ontop of the button so that it is clear that the panel is affecting the item where the panel comes out from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a sample on how you could do it. You may customize position as per need

```
RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
//_key refers to the key of the button on which you are overlaying the widget 
buttonPosition = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
var _overlayEntry= OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: buttonPosition.dy,//customize this to change position
      left: buttonPosition.dx,//customize this to change position
      child: //your widget
     );
    },
Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlayEntry);
//to remove 
_overlayEntry.remove();
```

Or you could use already built packages like
flutter_portal